# button onclick textfield validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text filed with id='codeCityId' and a button with onclick method. OnClick it will check the function

```
function click()={
var valid = $('#codeCityId').val().replace(/ /g,'').match(/^[A-Za-z]{1,}-[A-Za-z])+)?$/);
    if(valid){alert("valid")}else{alert("Not valid")}
}
```

The value of text filed should be like string - sting2. For example a-b. It should not accept any other expressions.How to check it?

Comment: add your code to fiddle !

Comment: `function click()={` <- syntax error on first line

Comment: can you correct it buddy??

Comment: @androidsuckzzz : There seems to be a problem in your regular expression. Have a look at my answer. hope it will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#btn").on("click",function(){
alert($('#codeCityId').val());
  var valid = $('#codeCityId').val().match(/^[A-Za-z]*-[A-Za-z]*$/);
if(valid){
    alert("valid");
}
else
{
   alert("Not valid");
}
```

});

[**Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/a00vx9dj/7/)

Comment: This code not working!!Can you correct?? Error in this expreesion  var valid = $('#codeCityId').val().replace(/ /g,'').match(/^[A-Za-z]   {1,}-[A-Za-z])+)?$/);

Comment: @NeerajDubey It should take only string like A-B. In your example it is accepting all. First sting - second string. Hope you understand

Comment: @NeerajDubey it is not working for big strings asas-asas. Can you modify? it will be helpful

Comment: @androidsuckzzz I believe your problem is resolved.If yes plz accept answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the below code. Hope it will help you to solve your problem :

```
$('#submitButton').click(function () {
    var reg = new RegExp(/^\S[A-Za-z]*-\S[A-Za-z]*$/);
    var valid = $('#codeCityId').val().replace(/ /g, '').match(reg);
    if (valid) {
        alert("valid");
    } else {
        alert("Not valid");
    }
});
```

Comment: buddy it works partailly. Check abc- It showing valid. String1-String2. Sting1 and String2 can not be empty. its compulsary. Please help dude

Comment: Update your regex to `/^\S[A-Za-z]*-\S[A-Za-z]*$/` as mentioned in updated answer

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your code I noticed a syntax error at **function click()={**

Change and try it as:

```
function click(){
   var valid = $('#codeCityId').val().replace(/ /g,'').match(/^[A-Za-z]{1,}-[A-Za-z])+)?$/);
   if(valid){alert("valid")}else{alert("Not valid")}
}
```

Comment: How you are calling this function? Can you please provide code snippet in fiddle or here, so it would be great to give clear solution

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control short3"  placeholder="Name-Code" name="codeCityValue" id="codeCityId" style="float:left; width:96% !important;" >
           <button type="button" onclick="CheckCityValidate()">Add Value</button>  function CheckCityValidate(){
   var valid = $('#codeCityId').val().replace(/ /g,'').match(/^[A-Za-z]{1,}-[A-Za-z])+)?$/);
   if(valid){alert("valid")}else{alert("Not valid")}
}

Comment: Sorry..!! I mean from where you are trying to call this function.

Comment: In button click inside a form

Comment: Is the button type is submit? And please paste the snippet line of your button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59787/discussion-between-androidsuckzzz-and-viswanath-d).